# Rejected for no Google logo - mapkit - but no way to show it

Tags: iphone, mapkit

My iPhone app just got rejected because I have screen that shows our location on a map, but Apple said it needed to show the Google logo on the map - I used mapkit for this (and CoreLocation)..nothing fancy and I did nothing to actively suppress the logo.  But when the map shows up in the application, there is no Google logo.  So, I'm confused.  How do you show the Google logo?  Here is the basic code I'm using to show the map:

```
    myMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    myMapView.zoomEnabled;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: 34.02008, longitude: -118.479707};
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01};
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};


MapController *annotation = [[MapController alloc]  initWithCoordinate:coord];
annotation.currentPoint = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
annotation.mTitle = @"InsightLA";
annotation.mSubTitle = @"1430 Olympic Blvd, Santa Monica, CA.";


[myMapView addAnnotation:annotation];

[annotation release];
[myMapView setRegion:region];
[self.view addSubview:myMapView];
myMapView.delegate =self;
```

Comment: maybe another view is covering it by accident?

Comment: it's because he inits with self.view.bounds. The Google logo is further down, mapview needs to be shorter.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the frame of the map is large enough in height to push the Google logo off-screen, or another view is covering it.

Keep reducing the height of the map in small chunks until you see the Google logo at the bottom left. Then work from there.

Here's one example of a partially suppressed logo I found on the net. This looks to be happening possibly because of the status bar height.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Anurag is right.

You, probably, forget to setup autoresizing:

```
mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the size of the frame of the mapview. I had the same problem myself, but I changed it to:

```
 MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370)];
```

That should do the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not as familiar with mapkit but you could always add a CA Layer with an image of the Google logo at like .aplha=5; within it. Not a great answer but a workaround if your desperate :)

Comment: Thanks all, I tried changing the parameters, but that didn't help..can't seem to figure this one out, but thanks for thinking about it.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. My map is **fullscreen** with status bar. I use only **portrait mode**, so resizing map height to **416** exactly fills my screen.

Comment: And then a device with a different screen size comes along. You MUST set up autoresizing or use autolayout.

Comment: @MaciejSwic sure, I just gave a tip why that problem appears.